# PPA packages versions

Tags: application-development, ppa

I am developing an open-source Java application and want to distribute it for Ubuntu (12.04+) users through a PPA.

My app depends on a Trove4j library v3+, but there is only 2.1 version of this library in the official Ubuntu Precise repository. Starting from Quantal there is a [trove3](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/trove3) package containing required version of the library. I don't want to make a downgrade to 2.1 version (because of performance issues in that old version).

What is the best way to overcome this limitation?

Maybe I can make a fork of [the official trove3 package](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/trove3) in my PPA or just copy trove3 source, change codename etc. and upload it as a separate package to my PPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the trov3 package you want is not in backports, then IMO best package it in your ppa.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

Comment: Thank you! There is no trove3 package in backports, so I will package it in my PPA, moreover it is needed only for precise.

Comment: You are most welcome.